# How to change Tab to RTL in native base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

How can I change tabs order from right to left.

Now is: Men  Women  Home

I need(RTL):  Home Women Men

**And Men should be default and active.**

```
<Tabs tabContainerStyle={{ height: 35 }}>
          <Tab heading="Men">
            <Text>example</Test>
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Women">
            <Text>example</Test>
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Home">
            <Text>example</Test>
          </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: if you still face issue. i have work. around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple just change the order

```
  <Tabs tabContainerStyle={{ height: 35 }}>
               <Tab heading="Home">
                <Text>example</Test>
              </Tab>
              <Tab heading="Women">
                <Text>example</Test>
              </Tab>
             <Tab heading="Men">
                <Text>example</Test>
              </Tab>
    </Tabs>
```

Comment: yes it should be for making native base rtl for Persian app just try reordering components , movafagh bashi :))))

Comment: tab ha native base bug daran khili is in stefadeh kon https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

Comment: Are in khobe... merciiiiiiiiiiiiiii